# How to get any tag ID

Tags: wp-query, functions, filters, tags, id

I want to exclude a certain tag from my home page not a category only post that hold the tag for example "olive";

I found a function for that which is like this

```
    function exclude_tag($query) {
if ( $query->is_home) {
    $query-> set('tag__not_in',array(x));
    }
return $query;
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts','exclude_tag');
```

Whereas X is the ID of the tag I want to exclude. How can I find  that ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your admin, go to Posts > Tags and then click edit for the tag you're after - the URL in your browser address bar will look like:

```
http://example.com/wp-admin/edit-tags.php?action=edit&taxonomy=post_tag&tag_ID=X&post_type=post
```

See the part where `tag_ID=X` - that X is your tag ID.

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to the backend to Posts -> Tags, click a tag to edit, then look
   at the URL and you should see `tag_ID=`. That is the ID.
2. Or use [`get_term_by()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_by) --
   `get_term_by('slug','term_slug','post_tag');`